# Hidden password field not displaying php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, passwords, hidden

I have the following code and the intention is that on selecting a password protected quiz, the password input field is shown. If a quiz however, is not password protected (result==0), then the input box for the quiz password is hidden.

The code now however, hides it all the time, even when the quiz does have a password.

Any suggestions?

** Relevant PHP Code in the index.php**

```
    $("#quiz_form").change(function () {
           /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */
           var allbooks = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
           var dataString = "level=" + allbooks; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

           $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
   type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
   url: "get-quiz-by-level.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
   dataType: "json",
   data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
   success: function success(result) {

       /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
       var option = "";
       result
           .sort(function(a, b) {
               return a.quiz_name.localeCompare(b.quiz_name);
           })
           .forEach(function (quiz, i) {
               option += "<option value=\"" + quiz.id + "\">" + quiz.quiz_name + "</option>";
               if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz != 0) {
                   $("#thequizpassword").attr('required', true).removeAttr('disabled').show();
               } else if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz == 0) {
                   $("#thequizpassword").removeAttr('required').attr('disabled', true).hide();
               }
           });
       $("#got_quiz").show().html(option);
   }
});
       });
       $("#got_quiz").change(function () {
           /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */
           var allbooks = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
           var dataString = "quiz=" + allbooks; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */
           $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
               type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
               url: "check_quiz_pass.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
               data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
               success: function success(result) {
                   /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
                   if (result == 0) {
                       $("#thequizpassword").removeAttr('required').attr('disabled', true).hide();
                   } else {
                       $("#thequizpassword").attr('required', true).removeAttr('disabled').show();
                   }

               }
           });
       });
```

**HTML generating (Display) code in index.php**

```
            <form id="myForm" name="onlyForm" action="quiz.php" class="home"  method="POST">
                <select name="quiz_level" id="quiz_form" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected="true">-- Select The level of your Test --</option>
                    <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                    <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
                </select>
<select  class="form-control" name="quiz" id="got_quiz" style="display:none;"> <!--onchange="showUser(this.value)"-->


  </select>
  <input type="password" name="quiz_password" placeholder="Enter Quiz Password" style="display:none;" autocomplete="placeholder_password" required/>
```

And finally, in **quiz.php the code** that was changed in order to stop chrome from autofilling (this caused the problem in the first place).

```
 //Getting the questions from DB here
    $m_questions_from_DB = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quiz_id='$final_quiz_ID'
                                ");

        while (mysqli_num_rows($m_questions_from_DB)<1) {
            $user_msg = 'Hey, weird, but it seems there are no questions in this quiz!';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }
        if($_POST['consent'] != 1){
            $user_msg = 'Hey, You have to consent first to begin the quiz!';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }else if(($_POST['class_name'] == "non" && !empty($_POST['school_pin'])) || ($_POST['class_name'] != "non" && empty($_POST['school_pin']))){
            if($_POST['class_name'] == "non"){ echo "aakakakak"; }
            $user_msg = 'Hey, You have to insert correct school pin and choose your class'.$_POST['school_pin'].$_POST['class_name'];
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();

        }elseif($quiz_pass != '0' && !empty($_POST['quiz_password']) && $_POST['quiz_password'] != $quiz_pass){
            $user_msg = 'Hey, Enter a correct Quiz password';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit(); 


        }elseif($quiz_pass != '0' && !empty($_POST['quiz_password']) && $_POST['quiz_password'] != $quiz_pass){
            $user_msg = 'Please use IE, Firefox -We are resolving issues with Chrome';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: Your password field does not appear to have the id "thequizpassword" as your code expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because yur password input does not have `id="thequizpassword"` and in jour js code you have a line:

```
if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz != 0) {
    $("#thequizpassword").attr('required', true).removeAttr('disabled').show();
} else if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz == 0) {
    $("#thequizpassword").removeAttr('required').attr('disabled', true).hide();
}
```

So the only thing you have to do is to change this:

```
<input type="password" name="quiz_password" placeholder="Enter Quiz Password" style="display:none;" autocomplete="placeholder_password" required/>
```

To this:

```
<input id="thequizpassword" type="password" name="quiz_password" placeholder="Enter Quiz Password" style="display:none;" autocomplete="placeholder_password" required/>
```